Sampling vs IID assumption
It is a little bit hard to frame this question, because it is not clear to me either, but I hope its clear to the reader.  It’s like you sense a problem or concept but can’t quite put it into words, as if it’s just out of reach.
Many of the results in statistics rely on the assumption that the data points are iid - independent and identically distributed.
However, in real world where many of these results are applied, to get the data points, a randomly sampled small subset is used.
However, a randomly sampled subset of size $n$ is not really equivalent to $n$ iid variables, is it? For example, in the former, the chance that $x_1=x_2$ is zero, but if I have 2 iid variables, there's a small chance that they might be equal.
How does this sampling method mathematically reconcile with the iid assumption? I get that they're approx the same if the sample space is infinte, but that's not the case in most cases (e.g. opinion polls).

Why is the pobability that $X_1 = X_2$ in a randomly sampled subset of size $n$ zero?

Generally speaking, sampling theory and its cousin estimation theory do not make the assumption that the inclusion of two units in sample is independent. Instead, they make use of the fact that we have control over the sample design and so can, in some fashion, specify what the various probabilities are.
As a basic example, if you take a simple random sample of $n$ units from a population of $N$, then for each unit $i$ in the population we define the random variable $\delta_i$ to equal 1 if $i$ is in the sample and 0 if it isn't, and similarly we define $\delta_{ij}$ if units $i$ and $j$ are both in the sample and 0 otherwise. We can then show that $\pi_i = E(\delta_i) = \frac{n}{N}$ is the probability of inclusion for unit $i$, and the joint probability of $i$ and $j$ is
$$\pi_{ij} = E(\delta_{ij}) = \begin{cases} \frac{n(n-1)}{N(N-1)} & i \neq j \\ \frac{n}{N} & i = j \end{cases}$$
It's quite clear that $\pi_{ij} \neq \pi_i \pi_j$, so the $\delta_i$ are identically distributed but not independent. When it comes to estimating population values, this shows up in the variance calculation - for example, we can estimate the average value of the variable $y_i$ as $\hat{Y} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i \in s} y_i$, and the variance of this estimator is
$$Var(\hat{Y}) = \frac{1}{n}\left(1 - \frac{n}{N}\right)S_Y^2$$
where $S_Y^2$ is the standard variance of $Y$ across the whole population. The middle term $\left(1 - \frac{n}{N}\right)$ appears specifically because of the non-independence of the inclusion of sample units, and is known as the finite population correction. If the population were infinite, then this term would disappear, giving a similar result to what you'd get with sampling each unit independently, and if your sample is small enough relative to the population then this term becomes negligible.
In other parts of estimation theory, there's a second approach to your question. Rather than considering the inclusion of units in the sample as the random element, you can think about the unit values themselves as being randomly generated from some underlying model. In this framework, you may assume independence of how each unit behaves subject to conditioning on all relevant regressor variables. For example, if you were measuring the average height of adults, you might assume that once you've controlled for genetics and demographics that the remaining difference between two people is random even if they're, for example, twin brothers.
In yet a third framework, you combine both of these ideas - your data contains randomness from both the sample and the underlying population model, and you design your sample and estimators to incorporate both of these in some fashion.
